# iOS7 background task immediately loses CPU time

Tags: background, ios7

Until iOS7, when my app backgrounded, it had ~10 seconds before the OS took away its CPU.
In iOS7 this seems to have changed, so that the CPU is gone almost immediately. This creates quite a few problems.

I am aware of `-[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:]`, but the CPU is gone so quickly that, using the current implementation, my app is killed before it knows whether `beginBackground...` should be called or not.

1) Is this the known behavior of iOS7?

2) Is it possible to change the default CPU time allocated to the task when it goes to the background so that it is a few seconds instead of less than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't be entirely necessary, but with the problems you are having, you should put this in your AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // do this *immediately*
    backgroundTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // handle stuff
    }];

    // do what you need to do, including whether you need to go on.
    // If there is asyncronicity in here, it might get more complicated,
    // since at the end of that async stuff, you've always go to do this
    // call:

    [UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:backgroundTaskId];
}
```

Try that and let us know what happens (you really need to *also* end the background task in the expiration handler, but first things first).

Comment: thanks you. i will accept the answer since it is the right way to go about this. our code had a flaw in that it tried to begin the background task only when it was sure it needed it.
instead it should've started it and immediately stopped it if not necessary.